# FAB position changes when listview's setAdapter method is called

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I'm using [this](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton) library for the fab implementation.
As you can see in this [video](http://www.dropshots.com/ido567/date/2015-01-04/14:45:47), the fab position is changing when the fragment loads.
After debugging it, I found that the listview "setAdapter()" method causes the position change.
I don't have a clue why it's happening..

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/sad_face"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/no_leagues" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_new_league"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/orange"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/redDark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My fragment

```
public class LeagueListFragment extends MyFragment {
    @InjectView(android.R.id.list)   ListView mListView;
    @InjectView(android.R.id.empty)  LinearLayout mEmpty;

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        return new LeagueListFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_league_list, container, false);

        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);

        // Fetch league list and set up adapter
        List<League> list = League.getAll();
        mAdapter = new LeagueAdapter(getActivity(), list);

        // Set up ListView
        mListView.setEmptyView(mEmpty);
        mListView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray)));
        mListView.setDividerHeight(2);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Margin changes in the runtime on pre-Lollipop because shadow mustn't be taken into account when margins are set.
Try to disable the shadow by :

```
fab:fab_shadow="false"
```

Fixing the issue is not expected for now.. (See [makovkastar answer](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton/issues/97))